# Randomize the order of rows

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am creating an quiz in Excel. The structure is:

```
Serial No.  Question    Select the right option      Right/Wrong      Marks
```

I have a list of some questions and options for answers are in a dropdown list. I want to randomize the questions with their answer options [means I want to randomize whole row].

Is there any build in Excel function?

Comment: You would have a better chance of getting answers if you had a history of marking answers as accpeted.  8 questions and no accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

You might achieve an adequate result with the addition of a column containing `=RANDBETWEEN(x,y) and sorting entire rows on that column. Here x could be your lowest Serial No. and y the highest. Can be changed with <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Not truly random because of inherent (minor) deficiencies is how RANDBETWEEN works and since capable of producing duplicate values will tend to favour the status quo.

Comment: +1 Just use RAND() to avoid the duplicates. Since it's just for sorting, it doesn't have to look pretty. The column could even be hidden.